# How to log exception stacktrace into debug level?

Tags: scala, logging, akka, slf4j

Here is a list of debug level functions that used in akka:

```
def debug(message : scala.Predef.String)
def debug(template : scala.Predef.String, arg1 : scala.Any)
def debug(template : scala.Predef.String, arg1 : scala.Any, arg2 : scala.Any)
def debug(template : scala.Predef.String, arg1 : scala.Any, arg2 : scala.Any, arg3 : scala.Any)
def debug(template : scala.Predef.String, arg1 : scala.Any, arg2 : scala.Any, arg3 : scala.Any, arg4 : scala.Any)
```

Here error level functions list:

```
def error(cause : scala.Throwable, message : scala.Predef.String)
def error(cause : scala.Throwable, template : scala.Predef.String, arg1 : scala.Any)
def error(cause : scala.Throwable, template : scala.Predef.String, arg1 : scala.Any, arg2 : scala.Any)
def error(cause : scala.Throwable, template : scala.Predef.String, arg1 : scala.Any, arg2 : scala.Any, arg3 : scala.Any)
def error(cause : scala.Throwable, template : scala.Predef.String, arg1 : scala.Any, arg2 : scala.Any, arg3 : scala.Any, arg4 : scala.Any)
```

Because code used in high load system I need to log exception stacktrace only at debug level. To log during debug level I have to write:

```
//some where in try catch block
val log : akka.event.LoggingAdapter
val e : Exception

if (log.isDebugEnabled) {
    log.error(e, "Unexpected error")
}
```

Is there better alternatives in akka except mixing levels?

Comment: You have typo in the title. excetion?

Comment: Why don't you just use `log.debug` ? The underlying logging library is doing the same if check. If your string needs to concat some variables you should pass them as the other arguments (so that the string concat is only done if it is necessary)

Comment: because `log.debug` do not have Throuble parameter. And passing exception to  it parameter prints only `exception.getMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a type class that extends Akka logging in such a way that throwables can be logged on `warning`, `info` and `debug` level:

## AkkaThrowableLogging

```
import java.io.{PrintWriter, StringWriter}
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter

object AkkaThrowableLogging {
  implicit class LoggingAdapterOps(logger: LoggingAdapter) {

    private def throwableStr(t: Throwable): String = {
      val sw = new StringWriter()
      val pw = new PrintWriter(sw, true)
      t.printStackTrace(pw)
      sw.getBuffer.toString
    }

    private def concat(cause: Throwable, message: String) = s"$message\n${throwableStr(cause)}"

    /**
      * Log message at warning level, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def warning(cause: Throwable, message: String): Unit =
      logger.warning(concat(cause, message))

    /**
      * Message template with 1 replacement argument, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def warning(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any): Unit =
      logger.warning(concat(cause, template), arg1)

    /**
      * Message template with 2 replacement arguments, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def warning(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any, arg2: Any): Unit =
      logger.warning(concat(cause, template), arg1, arg2)

    /**
      * Message template with 3 replacement arguments, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def warning(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any): Unit =
      logger.warning(concat(cause, template), arg1, arg2, arg3)

    /**
      * Message template with 4 replacement arguments, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def warning(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any, arg4: Any): Unit =
      logger.warning(concat(cause, template), arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)

    /**
      * Log message at info level, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def info(cause: Throwable, message: String): Unit =
      logger.info(concat(cause, message))

    /**
      * Message template with 1 replacement argument.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def info(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any): Unit =
      logger.info(concat(cause, template), arg1)

    /**
      * Message template with 2 replacement arguments, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def info(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any, arg2: Any): Unit =
      logger.info(concat(cause, template), arg1, arg2)

    /**
      * Message template with 3 replacement arguments, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def info(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any): Unit =
      logger.info(concat(cause, template), arg1, arg2, arg3)

    /**
      * Message template with 4 replacement arguments, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def info(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any, arg4: Any): Unit =
      logger.info(concat(cause, template), arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)

    /**
      * Log message at debug level, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def debug(cause: Throwable, message: String): Unit =
      logger.debug(concat(cause, message))

    /**
      * Message template with 1 replacement argument.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def debug(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any): Unit =
      logger.debug(concat(cause, template), arg1)

    /**
      * Message template with 2 replacement arguments, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def debug(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any, arg2: Any): Unit =
      logger.debug(concat(cause, template), arg1, arg2)

    /**
      * Message template with 3 replacement arguments, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def debug(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any): Unit =
      logger.debug(concat(cause, template), arg1, arg2, arg3)

    /**
      * Message template with 4 replacement arguments, including the exception that caused the error.
      * @see [[LoggingAdapter]]
      */
    def debug(cause: Throwable, template: String, arg1: Any, arg2: Any, arg3: Any, arg4: Any): Unit =
      logger.debug(concat(cause, template), arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
  }
}
```

## Usage

```
import AkkaThrowableLogging._
log.warning(new Exception("FooBarBaz"), "Hello {}", "world")
```

Output:

```
[WARN] [10/16/2016 19:05:50.614] [ScalaTest-run-running-AkkaThrowableLoggingTest] [AkkaThrowableLoggingTest(akka://AkkaTest)] Hello world
java.lang.Exception: FooBarBaz
    at test.AkkaThrowableLoggingTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(AkkaThrowableLoggingTest.scala:12)
    at test.AkkaThrowableLoggingTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AkkaThrowableLoggingTest.scala:11)
    at test.AkkaThrowableLoggingTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AkkaThrowableLoggingTest.scala:11)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    ...
```

## Caveat: Log output on error level may differ from lower levels

The exception can not be passed to the underlying logging framework (e.g.log4j, logback, etc.), because Akka's LoggingAdapter does not provide the API for doing that. The exception can therefore not be formatted on that level, but is handled by the `throwableStr` function, which uses the default Java formatting (what you get when you call `printStackTrace`). The log output of a `log.error(e, ...)` *may* therefore differ from those to `log.warning(, ...)`, `log.info(e, ...)` or `log.debug(e, ...)`. Most of the time no difference will be noted, because the formatting for exceptions is the default formatting anyway.